# Couldn't execute Telnet when spawned through expect

Tags: telnet, expect, spawn

I am trying to spawn an telnet session through an expect script. But when I try to execute the script, I get the following error

spawn telnet xx.xx.xx.xx
couldn't execute "telnet": no such file or directory
    while executing
"spawn telnet [lindex $argv 0]"

I am trying to run the script on windows 2008 server R2.

I faced the same error even after executing the "spawn telnet" manually in the expect shell.

What could be problem?

Answer (score 0):

telnet application is not installed?

[Install Telnet Client](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Open a command prompt window. Click Start, type cmd in the Start Search box, and then press ENTER.

Type the following command:

```
pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"
```

If the User Account Control dialog box appears, confirm that the action it displays is what you want, and then click Continue.

When the command prompt appears again, the installation is complete.

If using cygwin you will need to install the inetutils package.

Comment: The Telnet client on my windows machine is already installed. I can execute telnet command successfully from my cmd prompt.
However when i try to spawn telent in expect shell, it doesn't seem to work.

C:\cygwin\bin>expect
expect1.1> swapn
invalid command name "swapn"
    while executing
"swapn "
expect1.2> spawn telnet
spawn telnet
couldn't execute "telnet": no such file or directory
    while executing
"spawn telnet"

Comment: You'll probably need to use the full command path. Do you have the inetutils package installed in cygwin?

Comment: I didn't get the full path part of your command & I don't think i have inetutils in cygwin installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I resolved this issue by downloading `plink.exe` and placing it in the same folder as my expect script.  The download is located [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html). I then called it using `spawn plink -telnet $ipaddress`